# SQL: How to SELECT different values from a table in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

Table 'Teams' has two columns

```
teamID,
teamName
```

Table 'Match' has three columns

```
matchID, 
teamID_1,
teamID_2
```

... like in image bellow:

[image]

How would I construct a select statement which will pull through the `Teams.teamName` to both the `Match.teamID_1` and the `Match.teamID_2` based on their respective IDs?

I can do that only with one column or another, but not both:

```
SELECT Match.matchID, Teams.teamName
    FROM Match
    INNER JOIN Teams ON Match.teamID_1 = Teams.teamID
```

OR

```
SELECT Match.matchID, Teams.teamName
    FROM Match
    INNER JOIN Teams ON Match.teamID_2 = Teams.teamID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the same table multiple times. Just alias them (`t1` and `t2` as shown below):

```
SELECT 
    Match.matchID, 
    t1.teamName, 
    t2.teamName
FROM Match
    INNER JOIN Teams t1 ON Match.teamID_1 = t1.teamID
    INNER JOIN Teams t2 ON Match.teamID_2 = t2.teamID
```